# Firefox - How to preload newtab page

Tags: firefox

I set my new tab page to http://www.google.com and it takes a while before it fully load up. I want it be preloaded on the background or directly to my memory so that if I open a new tab it will immediately display and be fully functional, and also to save data from connecting to the internet. I have a really slow internet connection and with insufficient data allocation per month.

Comment: Old question.  If this is still a problem, have you looked at pinning google.com so it's a "permanent" tab?  That will leave it ready to use, then select something else for your newtab page.

Answer (score 0):

If the *Slow Connection* or *insufficient data allocation* is the issue here, I suggest changing the `New Tab` page to `about:blank` and type your query directly into `Search Box` (adjacent to URL bar) or the `URL Bar` itself. That will save you from even loading Google page again and again for every new query.